# Autofac trying to load irrelevant class

Tags: c#, autofac, nopcommerce

I upgraded nopCommerce from version 4.30 to the newest version 4.40.3
I had three plugins which worked well in version 4.30, but are not working in the newest version.
I already updated all relevant code which changed with the update of the newest version and everything is compiling without any issues.

But when I try to install one of these plugins in the new version I'm getting the following error message:

> Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.NoConstructorsFoundException: 'No accessible constructors were found for the type 'System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirecory.DomainController'.'

> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.GetDefaultPublicConstructors(Type type)
> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder.FindConstructors(Type targetType)
> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ConfigurePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices componentRegistryServices, IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder)
> at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices registryServices, IResolvePipelineBuilder pipelineBuilder)
> at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistration.BuildResolvePipeline(IComponentRegistryServices registryServices)
> at Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentRegistryBuilder.Build()
> at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
> at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProviderFactory.CreateServiceProvider(ContainerBuilder containerBuilder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ServiceFactoryAdapter`1.CreateServiceProvider(Object containerBuilder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at Nop.Web.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Git\Webentwicklung\NopCommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web\Program.cs:line 16

The class [DomainController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domaincontroller?view=net-5.0) comes from the *System.DirectoryServices* package, so I can't directly change anything on this specific class.
This dll is getting loaded, because one of my plugins has a reference to a dll on which this package is installed.

The Plugin could be installed without any issues and with the same configuration in the previous version which also used Autofac.

Inside nopCommerce I don't need any of the functionalities which this package provides.

So my question is the following: Is it somehow possible to tell Autofac to just ignore this assembly or this specific class?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Presumably one of your services that you've registered with Autofac takes `DomainController` in its constructor. The full error message should tell you which service.

Comment: @Llama the problem is that this is the full error message I'm getting. If I look into the call stack i just the internal methods of Autofac, but not where the error is occuring in my code.

Comment: Can you copy everything including the stack trace into your question, please?

Comment: @Llama I added the stack trace of the exception

Comment: Check related issue here
https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1050#issuecomment-557268729